# Wanted: Simple invertible function with the following properties

Tags: functions, analyticity

The function

$$f(x) = x \tanh(\frac{\pi}{2}\sinh{x})$$

has useful properties in numerical calculations as it is an even function that converges extremely quickly to $x$ for large input values. Difficulty arises in calculations where the inversion of the function is needed. I am looking for a function that is even, analytic in the complex plane, invertible and behaves linearly for large and goes like $x$ for large input $x$. It would also be optimal if the function converges quickly to linear.

Comment: Such a function will have $f'(0)=0$. It then cannot be inverted globally.

Comment: I see. There should still exist a function that can be locally inverted in the regions [0,$\infty$) and (-$\infty$, 0]. Correct?